# Double releasing an autoreleased object doesn't crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, autorelease

I was testing my code and I realized that I was releasing an autoreleased object but the app did not crash.
So I created a new empty project from scratch with just few lines:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
[array release];
[array release];
[array release];
[array release];
...
```

This does not crash never, nor is marked as zombie object in GDB. If I analyze the code with Product -> Analyze it does not find any errors.

Normally it should crash I think... 
I'm testing on Xcode 4.2 with Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 but the same is true with the old gcc 4.2.

Any idea about why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I think that you are running with different build settings than me. What compiler are you using and Xcode version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a no-op if garbage collection is enabled. I presume, it is.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I come from the old memory model without garbage collection so I was expecting to see a crash.

Comment: So do I and being unexperienced in objective-c I went straight to look up the documentation for NSObject release, to see if different cases are outlined there :)